# MongoDB client in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb

Im trying to connect mongodb in node.js and take the link to client to the outer variable.

I need to create a module that would return a result of .find() method. How can i do this?

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

let client
mongoClient = new MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/', {useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true})
mongoClient.connect((err, db) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err)
    }
    client = db
})

const database =  client.db('db')
const collection = database.collection('collection')

client.close()
```

And the error

```
const database =  client.db('db')
                         ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'db' of undefined
```

Comment: `mongoClient.connect` is asynchronous, you have to use `await` or place `client.db` inside callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment suggests, you can use async/await to wait for the connection to be established, and do the error handling with a try/catch statement:

```
try {
  const client = await mongoClient.connect()
  const database =  client.db('db')
  const collection = database.collection('collection')
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e)
}
```

Don't forget to use it in an async function.

**Update**

An async function example, you may want to return the collection:

```
const getData = async () => {
  try {
    mongoClient = new MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/', {useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true})
    const client = await mongoClient.connect()
    const database =  client.db('db')
    const collection = database.collection('collection')
    client.close()
    return collection
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
```

Comment: it seems that i having troubles with it

`const client = await mongoClient.connect()
                  
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`

Comment: You should use it inside an async function, check https://javascript.info/async-await

Comment: oh, yes, i understand. thank you very much

Comment: I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

after uri you must define db name

```
mongoClient = new MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/', {useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true})
```

like this

```
mongoClient = new MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/shop', {useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true})
```